# misunderstanding about convergence in Schwartz space

Tags: functional-analysis

On page 158 of [this book](https://books.google.com/books?id=IK4PBgAAQBAJ&q=158#v=snippet&q=not%20a%20hilbert%20space&f=false) the author states that the sequence $f_n(x)=e^{-nx^2}$ is Cauchy in $\mathcal{S}(R)$ but it is convergent to a discontinuous function and then he concludes that $\mathcal{S}(R)$ is incomplete. The argument seems incorrect to me as the given sequence converges to the zero function in the norm induced by the inner product. Would it be correct to say that the author has confused pointwise convergence with convergence in the 2-norm? To show incompleteness of $\mathcal{S}(R)$ I think he could have used $g_n(x)=e^{-\sqrt{x^2+1/n}}$. I appreciate any thoughts on this.

Answer (score 1):

The text confuses me, as the author has not mentioned what topology we are working in. It would appear that $\mathcal{S} (\mathbb{R})$ is treated as you say, as a space of continuous functions with the topology of pointwise convergence, rather than, for example a subspace of $L^p$ with the usual equivalence modulo equality a.e. which would be convenient to develop Hilbert Space theory.

Under the norm topology of $L^2(\mathbb{R})$, one could show that $\mathcal{S} (\mathbb{R})$ is not closed, hence not complete, by proving that it is dense in $L^2$ (this can be done via bump functions), and that there are non-Schwartz $L^2$ functions.

Another standard way to view the Schwartz Space $\mathcal{S} (\mathbb{R}^n)$ is as the topological vector space generated by the family of seminorms: $\sup_{\mathbb{R}^n}|x^\alpha D^\beta f(x)|$ under which the Schwartz Space is in fact a Fréchet space, in particular complete in that topology.

Comment: The main issue from my pov is that the author is stating that $f_n$ is Cauchy in 2-norm but it does not converge in $S(R)$. Do you agree with the claims that (a) indeed $f_n$ converges in 2-norm to the zero function (which gives a shorter proof of Cauchyness too), and (b) the sequence $g_n$ that I have defined is Cauchy but not convergent in $S(R)$ wrt the 2-norm?

Comment: Both statements are true:
 
a)It is true that $f_n \to 0$ in $L^2$ (and pointwise a.e.), which tells us nothing about non-completeness of $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$

b)It is also true that pointwise, and $L^2$, $g_n \to e^{|x|} \notin \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$, from which it follows as you say that $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R})$ is not complete in $L^2$.

My biggest complaint is that the author does not identify functions a.e., without which the 2-"norm" is not positive definite, hence not a norm.

Comment: Thanks. The a.e identification is not required in $S(R)$ because the Schwartz functions are continuous (smooth).